# Query where column match one or all, according to an argument

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Sorry if this is basic. I have a function that get as an argument **one** of these 2 :

```
subjects ['ALL']. //search for any subject
subjects ['A','B','C'] //only one of these
```

So in my function I need to query according to `subjects` argument

```
def function (subjects):
    
    query = ('''
                SELECT date_num, subject, in_col
                FROM base
                WHERE subject in {subjects} // = subject in ('A','B','C') works, but what about ALL ?

        ''').format(subjects=subjects)
```

so when the subjects to be found are `a,b,c` there is no problem, but how can I tell it to search for **ALL** subjects in the case argument is ALL ?

Could I send `*` instead ? `like subjects[*]` ?

(I do turn the `['a','b']` into `('a','b')` in my code )

Comment: just don't add the `where` clause.

Comment: How about dropping the whole "WHERE ..." part altogether?

Comment: sorry can you show me ? I need to have the same single function for both cases, if I drop it how can specify for the case of a,b,c only ? thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a dynamic SQL Query from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53256723/creating-a-dynamic-sql-query-from-python)

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki so how can I satisfy both cases? like a,b,c or ALL in the same function ?

Comment: Do you mean IS NOT NULL?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
subjects = ['ALL']
# subjects = ['A', 'B']
where_clause = f"WHERE subject in {tuple(subjects)}" if subjects[0] != "ALL" else ""

query = f'''SELECT date_num, subject, in_col FROM base {where_clause}'''
```

Try uncommenting the second line to check how the query modifies

Answer (score 1):

Create a generic query and add the where clause if needed

```
query = "SELECT date_num, subject, in_col FROM base"
if subjects[0] != "ALL":
    query += f" WHERE subject in {subjects}"
```